# Perform Segue called before dismiss ContactPicker

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact

On `didSelect` of CNContachPicker I'm calling one segue but that is not working as when user clicks on any contact `didSelect` is first called then dismiss. How to handle such scenarios ?

```
    func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "AToB", sender: contact)

}
```

Comment: try adding dissmis function below self.performSegue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {

picker.dismiss(animated:true, completion: {
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "AToB", sender: contact)

    })
 }
```

You should dismiss the `ContactPicker` first. Use the completion block. When the picker is dismissed and then you can perform any operations. It's just works